# How to print variables which are on the header on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that is not working correctly and I need to check what it is happening. The problem is that most of the code is done on the html header. How can I print the variables in order to check what's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highstock Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.getJSON('http://localhost/teste04.php', function(data) {

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ]);
    }

    // set the allowed units for data grouping
    var groupingUnits = [[
        'week',                         // unit name
        [1]                             // allowed multiples
    ], [
        'month',
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
    ]];

    // create the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },

        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: 200,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: 300,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
    });
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I would like to print "datalength" for example.

Thanks in advance,
Luis

Comment: what "variables" do u want to print

Comment: line 21 is missing a semi colon.   
            `volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ]);`

Comment: semi colon added and the variable could be "datalength"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables inside the anonymous function you pass as parameter callback to $.getJSON only live inside it's scope.
You can use something like console.log(dataLength) inside that function and its value at that time will show up in the browser's console.
You can use a javascript debugger (firebug in firefox, Javascript Console in Chrome), set up a break point on the first line inside that function and execute it step by step to see the values in each variable.

Chrome, imho, has the best console and debugger, so just try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/teste04.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
    ............
```

hit F12 on chrome, refresh the page and whatch all the values inside the data object in the console

Comment: Thanks, for the sake of the answear it worked. The issue seems that inside the getJSON I cannot get it to run...

like this it works:
$(function() {
    console.log("1");
     $.getJSON('teste04.php', function(data) {

like this it doesn't work
[17:59:18.597] GET http://localhost/TraderMananger/Highstock/teste04.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1606ms]
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('teste04.php', function(data) {
  // split the data set into ohlc and volume
                console.log("1");

without any error...

Comment: something is wrong there, because if the AJAX call goes right, the anonymous function is executed and receives the parameter data so you must be able to console log it.

Comment: It seems that the problem is on the getJSON which I'm not able to make it work. I'll create a new issue to see if i'm able to make it work. Thanks

Comment: maybe the teste04.php is not returning the correct data, it you should do header('Content-type: application/json'); echo json_encode($yourdata);

Comment: Ok, it is solved, I had an error on the json_encode... Thanks for the help.